# Какую среду разработки использовать для Django?

Tags: python, django, ide

Решил изучить Django, до этого писал код в бесплатной версии Pycharm, но насколько я понимаю поддержка Django проектов только в платной версии. Поэтому хотел бы спросить какой IDE лучше всего использовать для Django

Comment: Да хоть виндовым Блокнотом. Какая разница?

Comment: Я VS Code юзаю, хоть это и не IDE, но с плагинами практически становится им.

Comment: я PyCharm использую

Comment: Если вы являетесь учеником/студентом, то у Вас есть возможность получить `PyCharm Pro` в образовательных целях. Например, через `GitHub Student Developer Pack`. Думаю, это хорошее решение для обучения (если оно Вам подойдёт, конечно).

Comment: Использую обычный бесплатный PyCharm. У платного есть поддержка Django, но и так нормально. Часто в видео вижу, что используют Atom. Вообще, думаю, особой разницы нет.

Comment: Атом IDE очень загромождает машину. Pycharm лучшее решение для питона.@andreymal интересно как вы бы писали в нотепаде?(с кучей файлов, html синтаксисом, python синтаксисом , django template language и т.д.) :) ?

Comment: @Victor мне тоже нравится pycharm, но когда я работаю со своим django проектом он высвечивает что для django у них есть платная версия программы, и я думаю, не помешает ли мне урезанная community версия в будущем

Comment: Не знаю ,думаю нет(хотя я недавно начал заниматься джанго).В конце концов можно поставить когда будет нужно pycharm professional ,но я думаю так можно обойтись.(В конце концов многие другие редакторы вообще не имеют специальной поддержки джанго)

Comment: @Victor ну да, вы наверное правы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я лично использую PyCharm. Так как работаю в Сбербанке, у них есть лицензионная версия для версии Professional.

Очень удобная программа для написания сайта, есть интеллисенс, плюс очень хорошее взаимодействие между urls, views, models и прочее.

Разметка для html, css, js